# ¿Cómo desplegar sólo los campos DATETIME con la hora más temprana y la más tarde de una fecha?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada *eventos*:

| id | no_empleado | tipo | checada |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 100 | Entrada | 2021-06-01 07:02:00 |
| 02 | 100 | Entrada | 2021-06-01 07:03:00 |
| 03 | 100 | Salida | 2021-06-01 14:03:00 |
| 04 | 100 | Salida | 2021-06-01 14:04:00 |
| 05 | 200 | Entrada | 2021-06-01 07:12:00 |
| 06 | 200 | Entrada | 2021-06-01 07:13:00 |
| 07 | 200 | Salida | 2021-06-01 14:03:00 |
| 08 | 200 | Salida | 2021-06-01 14:04:00 |
| 09 | 100 | Entrada | 2021-06-02 07:12:00 |
| 10 | 100 | Entrada | 2021-06-02 07:13:00 |
| 11 | 100 | Salida | 2021-06-02 14:03:00 |
| 12 | 100 | Salida | 2021-06-02 14:04:00 |

Estoy tratando de que se me despliegue **solamente** una entrada y una salida por cada fecha (la entrada más temprana y la salida más tarde de ese día) y que me despliegue sólo las entradas y salidas del *no_empleado* que específicamente deseo.

Digamos que quiero ver las entradas y salidas filtradas del empleado con el *no_empleado* **100**.  Debería obtener el siguiente resultado:

| no_empleado | tipo | checada |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Entrada | 2021-06-01 07:02:00 |
| 100 | Salida | 2021-06-01 14:04:00 |
| 100 | Entrada | 2021-06-02 07:12:00 |
| 100 | Salida | 2021-06-02 14:04:00 |
|  |  |  |

¿Qué *query* me puede dar el resultado que busco?

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una opción es agrupar por no_empleado, tipo y la fecha (solo la fecha, sin tener en cuenta la hora: `DATE(checada)`), y utilizar un `CASE` en función del tipo, si es una "Entrada" retornará el mínimo valor para checada y sino (si es una "Salida") retornará el máximo valor para checada.

```
SELECT no_empleado, 
       tipo, 
       CASE WHEN tipo = 'Entrada' THEN MIN(checada) ELSE MAX(checada) END AS checada
FROM eventos
WHERE no_empleado = 100
GROUP BY no_empleado, tipo, DATE(checada);
```

Salida a partir de los datos de ejemplo de la pregunta:

| no_empleado | tipo | checada |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Entrada | 2021-06-01 07:02:00 |
| 100 | Salida | 2021-06-01 14:04:00 |
| 100 | Entrada | 2021-06-02 07:12:00 |
| 100 | Salida | 2021-06-02 14:04:00 |

Comment: Muchas gracias, era la solución que estaba buscando

Comment: De nada @JorgeDuran!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ya intentaste agrupar. Esto debería darte el resultado deseado:

```
SELECT no_empleado, min(checada), max(checada) FROM `eventos` WHERE no_empleado = 100
GROUP BY no_empleado
```

He preparado un pequeño ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @TABLA AS TABLE (Id int, no_empleado int, tipo varchar(50), checada datetime)
INSERT INTO @TABLA
VALUES ('1',    '100',  'Entrada'   ,'2021-06-01 07:02:00'),
('2',   '100',  'Entrada',  '2021-06-01 07:03:00'),
('3',   '100'   ,'Salida',  '2021-06-01 14:08:00'),
('4',   '100',  'Salida', '2021-06-01 14:04:00')

SELECT no_empleado, MIN(checada) minchecada, MAX(checada) maxchecada
FROM @TABLA t
WHERE no_empleado = 100
GROUP BY no_empleado
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
no_empleado minchecada              maxchecada
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
100         2021-01-06 07:02:00.000 2021-01-06 14:08:00.000
```

Comment: En el resultado deseado tanto entradas más tempranas como salidas más tardes de cada fecha se encuentran en la misma columna

Comment: Entonces debes quitar del select  y del group by la columna tipo. voy a editar mi respuesta

Comment: Creo que tomaste el ejemplo de lo que **no** busco para ejemplificar una posible solución. Ya edité mi pregunta y quité esa parte para evitar confusiones. Gracias igualmente por tomarte el tiempo de responder.